# Windows Remote Desktop Client connecting timeout waiting for wake up

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, timeout

I connect between two Windows 10 Pro PCs. While the destination PC is hibernated, Remote Desktop Client wakes it up and waits few seconds for establishing the connection.

The problem is that remote pc needs bit more time to wake up than client waits for. As a result, error comes out with message that remote host is not available. I need to connect again in few seconds.

How can I increase timeout for client to wait until destination pc responds? I guess this must be a registry entry if any, as there is no GUI setting available.

This is different from questions on connection / idle timeout.